# Insert element to parent <li> in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, parent

i need to insert span or div to parent li. For spoiler or button to use it in classie.js

```
<ul>
   <li class="parent">
        <a href=""></a>
        <ul></ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I know that i should use walker in wordpress... but i dont know function

Comment: You're say "to" parent. Do you mean under the parent? And when you say insert, do you mean with javascript?

Comment: Not under, inside. For example i need this <li class="parent"><a></a><span></span></li>. And no, by PHP

Comment: That is "under" -- in PHP you just put `<?php echo '<span></span>'; ?>` - is that all you're asking for?

Comment: where do you want to add this? wp_nav_menu?